# Does Excel Online support filtering columns by value?

Tags: excel-online

One of our customers shared to us an Excel Online document for exchanging notes and bug reports, the file is starting to grow quite a bit, and could benefit from filtering: one of the columns represents a "status" (To do, In progress, Done, Won't fix, etc.) but I can't find a way to apply the usual Excel filter which allows you to choose values and only show some rows.

Sample scenario: only show the rows in which the "status" column contains the value "To Do". In "offline" Excel, I'd simply use the "filter" function... Can it be done at all in Excel Online ?

*Clarification:* all the contents of the document are plain text, the only "magic" in place is that this 'Status' column changes background depending on what is written inside it (green for 'done', orange for 'todo', etc.

*Clarification #2:* I didn't realize before that the document comes from the customer's Sharepoint Online platform (I can see "Guest Contributor" on screen while I write), I don't know if it's relevant though. I cannot provide a link to the document, since it contains privileged information.

Comment: I can't find this "filter drop down" they refer to in the link

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about it, but I added some clarifications which might help figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm late in the party but not empty handed.*

### **Yes**, Excel online does support filtering.

Just format your column as table and then select the kind of filter you want to apply.

Refer to [this technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/excel-online-service-description.aspx) for complete feature list.